# dynamic array of LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, dynamic-arrays

This is a simpler version of something I'm working on. When the add button is pressed, what is supposed to happen is, a LinearLayout is created and a CheckBox is also created with the text within the EditText box. The CheckBox is then placed into the newly created LinearLayout, and the newly created LinearLayout, placed in the already existing LinearLayout(named layout). I know it seems unnecessary to create a new LinearLayout but in the main program, its really important. My problem is, when I run the code, the app 'force closes' so I want to know what it is that I'm doing wrong or if there is a better approach I can take to achieve the result I need.

```
package co.cc.*******.toDo;

import co.cc.*******.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ToDoMainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button bAdd,bremove;
    EditText et;
   // CheckBox cbNew;
    LinearLayout layout;//main layout
    ArrayList<CheckBox> cbNew;//dynamic array of checkBoxes
    ArrayList<LinearLayout> cbLayout;//dynamic array of LinearLayouts
    int index = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initialize();

        bAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        bremove.setOnClickListener(this);
    }//end method onCreate

    void initialize(){
        bAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        bremove = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bremove);
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
        cbNew = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

    }//end method initialize

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.bAdd:
            cbLayout.add(index, new LinearLayout(this));//create new layout to store cb
            cbNew.add(index, new CheckBox(this));//create new checkbox
            cbNew.get(index).setText(et.getText().toString()+ index);//set text to text in editText box
            cbLayout.get(index).addView(cbNew.get(index));//add checkbox to newly created layout
            layout.addView(cbLayout.get(index));//add newly created layout to already existing layout
            index ++;
            break;

        }//end switch

                //layout.removeView(cbNew.get(index));

    }//end method onClick

}//end class ToDoMainActivity
```

Comment: `cbLayout` not initialised? These things can usually easily be spotted  in the logs. In general it is a good practice to check the output of LogCat and before posting a question on SO, and adding whatever is in the logs to the question.